# Why my drop down list is not working?

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu

I have made this drop down from the following website:

[**Inspirational Pixels**](http://inspirationalpixels.com/tutorials/creating-a-dropdown-menu-with-html-css)

Here is my HTML code:

```
<td class="dess rec">
    <a href="#" id="l_desserts" >desserts</a>
        <ul class="submenu">
            <li><a href="#">Cake</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Ice Cream</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Shahi Kheer</a></li>
        </ul>
 </td>
```

It is a part of a table

CSS:

```
.submenu {
    position:absolute;
    overflow:hidden;
    opacity:0;
    background-color:#444;
    width:100px;
    top:37px;
    left:-3px;
    border-top:2px solid #fff;
}
.submenu>li {
    list-style:none; 
    margin-left:-40px;
    margin-top:3px;
}
.submenu>li>a {
    display:block;
    text-decoration:none;
    color:#fff;
    border:2px solid #444;
    border-radius:5px;
    padding:4px;
    text-align:center;
    font-family:Lucida Sans Unicode;
}
.submenu>li>a:hover {
    border:2px solid white;
}
#l_desserts:hover .submenu {
z-index:1;
    opacity: 1;
}
```

What my problem is that this drop down list is not working here in this case but earlier I made a drop down list using this method. You can see this here (the following link is of a blogger):

**[Indian Tadka](http://savitafood.blogspot.in/)**

The same method is applied in here. I dont know Why it is not working>

```css
body{
margin:0px;
}
#header{
 height: 90px;
 background-color: #444;
 margin:0px;
 color: #fff;
}

#logo{
 width:70px;
 height:90px;
 background-image: url('../images/logo.jpg');
 background-size: 70px 90px;
 position:absolute;
 z-index:2;
 color:#fff;
 text-align: center;
 font-family: arial;
 font-weight: bold;
 text-shadow: 2px 1px #000;
 cursor: pointer;
}

#complete_name{
 position:absolute;
 top:0px;
 color:#fff;
 font-family:arial;
  font-weight:bold;
  font-size:20px;
  z-index:1;
 background-color:#444; 
}

#nav{
 position:absolute;
 left:75px;
 color:#fff;
 z-index:0;
 top:37px;
}

#l_desserts, #l_rice{
 color:#fff;
 text-decoration:none;
 padding-left:24px;
 font-family: Lucida Sans Unicode;
 display:block;
 background-image: url('../images/coffie_paper_texture.jpg');
 background-position:center;
 background-size: 100px 20px;
}

.rec{
 width:100px;
}
.otl{
 width:100px;
 background-color:#717171;
}

.submenu{
 position:absolute;
 overflow:hidden;
 opacity:0;
 background-color:#444;
 width:100px;
 top:37px;
 left:-3px;
 border-top:2px solid #fff;
}
.submenu>li{
 list-style:none; 
 margin-left:-40px;
 margin-top:3px;
}
.submenu>li>a{
 display:block;
 text-decoration:none;
 color:#fff;
 border:2px solid #444;
 border-radius:5px;
 padding:4px;
 text-align:center;
 font-family:Lucida Sans Unicode;
}
.submenu>li>a:hover{
 border:2px solid white;
}
#l_desserts:hover .submenu{
z-index:1;
 opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<header id="header"> 
  <div id="logo" onmouseover="show_name()" onmouseout="hide_name()"> </div>
  <font id="complete_name"></font>
  <table id="nav">
   <tr id="Oth_links">
   <td class="photoGall Otl"><a id="pg" href="#">Photo Gallery</a></td>
   </tr>
   <tr id="toRecipes">
     <td class="dess rec">
   <a href="#" id="l_desserts" >desserts</a>
   <ul class="submenu">
    <li><a href="#">Cake</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Ice Cream</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Shahi Kheer</a></li>
   </ul>
     </td>
     <td class="rice rec">
   <a href="#" id="l_rice">Rice</a>
     </td>     
   </tr>   
  </table>
 </header>
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer

i just have to change my line:

```
#l_desserts:hover .submenu{ ...
```

to this:

```
#l_desserts:hover+.submenu
```

but it still dont know how the preceding method did worked in my blogger

```css
body{
margin:0px;
}
#header{
 height: 90px;
 background-color: #444;
 margin:0px;
 color: #fff;
}

#logo{
 width:70px;
 height:90px;
 background-image: url('../images/logo.jpg');
 background-size: 70px 90px;
 position:absolute;
 z-index:2;
 color:#fff;
 text-align: center;
 font-family: arial;
 font-weight: bold;
 text-shadow: 2px 1px #000;
 cursor: pointer;
}

#complete_name{
 position:absolute;
 top:0px;
 color:#fff;
 font-family:arial;
  font-weight:bold;
  font-size:20px;
  z-index:1;
 background-color:#444; 
}

#nav{
 position:absolute;
 left:75px;
 color:#fff;
 z-index:0;
 top:37px;
}

#l_desserts, #l_rice{
 color:#fff;
 text-decoration:none;
 padding-left:24px;
 font-family: Lucida Sans Unicode;
 display:block;
 background-image: url('../images/coffie_paper_texture.jpg');
 background-position:center;
 background-size: 100px 20px;
}

.rec{
 width:100px;
}
.otl{
 width:100px;
 background-color:#717171;
}

.submenu{
 position:absolute;
 overflow:hidden;
 opacity:0;
 background-color:#444;
 width:100px;
 top:37px;
 left:-3px;
 border-top:2px solid #fff;
}
.submenu>li{
 list-style:none; 
 margin-left:-40px;
 margin-top:3px;
}
.submenu>li>a{
 display:block;
 text-decoration:none;
 color:#fff;
 border:2px solid #444;
 border-radius:5px;
 padding:4px;
 text-align:center;
 font-family:Lucida Sans Unicode;
}
.submenu>li>a:hover{
 border:2px solid white;
}
#l_desserts:hover+.submenu{
 opacity:1;
 z-index:3;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<title>Indian Tadka- Home</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/main.css" type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/scr_home.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/JIO.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
 <header id="header"> 
  <div id="logo" onmouseover="show_name()" onmouseout="hide_name()"> </div>
  <font id="complete_name"></font>
  <table id="nav">
   <tr id="Oth_links">
   <td class="photoGall Otl"><a id="pg" href="#">Photo Gallery</a></td>
   </tr>
   <tr id="toRecipes">
     <td class="dess rec">
   <a href="#" id="l_desserts" onmouseover="showDess();" >desserts</a>
   <ul class="submenu">
    <li><a href="#">Cake</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Ice Cream</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Shahi Kheer</a></li>
   </ul>
     </td>
     <td class="rice rec">
   <a href="#" id="l_rice">Rice</a>
     </td>     
   </tr>   
  </table>
 </header>

</body>
</html>
```